# can we resign the already signed jars in java?

Tags: java

I've a `.jar` file with an old signature and want to resign it with a new signature. Is it possible?

If it is possible: how to do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the signature is not one you own, you would need to unjar the jar first.

Like so (assume unix, translate to dos otherwise):

```
jar xvf JarName.jar

rm -rf META-INF

jar cvf JarName.jar *
```

Now you need to run jarsigner to sign the jar

```
jarsigner -keystore /yourkeystoredirectory/mystore -storepass yourpass
      -keypass yourkeypasswd JarName.jar keyname
```

If you don't have a keystore, you can create one with keytool.

Comment: "rm -rf META-INF" is an really bad idea. This delete important files like services directory too.

Answer (score 2):

I found a better solution on https://www.chemaxon.com/forum/viewpost35555.html#35555

1. Remove files with ".SF" or ".RSA" extension from the META-INF folder inside the jar.
2. Delete signing checksums from META-INF/MANIFEST.MF: each "Name" and "SHA1-Digest" fields should be deleted from META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.

A more comprehensive documentation can be found on the oracle documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Signed_JAR_File (for example there can be ".DSA" files in the META-INF folder, and files beginning with "SIG-" )

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the class files and re-jar them with your signature