# Is it possible to re-sign a Java applet with a newer certificate?

Tags: java, code-signing, jarsigner

I have a signed Java applet, and the certificate just expired. I have a new certificate, but I'm not sure that I can find the original, unsigned applet jar file. Is there any way that I can take the signed jar and replace the old certificate with a new one? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [can we resign the already signed jars in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162830/can-we-resign-the-already-signed-jars-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can't wrap it.

However, you should be able to simply re-sign the JAR with a different certificate.  Signing a JAR doesn't encrypt it in anyway.  It just adds stuff to the manifest section.

This is not a security issue.  The re-signed certificate is different to the original one, the end-user has to accept it all over again.  (I don't think you can avoid that ... because it *would* be a security issue!)

---

Anyway, the simple approach is to just try re-signing the signed applet JAR, and see whether it works, and how it behaves when you try to run it as a user.

Comment: Make sure to strip out the original signature information before signing with the new certificate.  If a Jar is signed by more than one certificate, there will be problems at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

To solve a similar situation I deleted all signature files under `META-INF/*.SF` and `META-INF/*.RSA` and signed it again.
`META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` now contains both the old (unused) lines with SHA-1 hash and the new SHA-256 ones; the remaining old ones don't seem to be a problem: `jarsigner -verify -verbose` reports everything's OK with the new signature.